# plot coordinates {(a_1,3) (a_2,2) (a_i,4) (a_r,1)} in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[ycomb] plot coordinates
    {(0,3) (1,2) (2,4) (3,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the output is:

[image]

but If I have the coordinates `{(a_1,3) (a_2,2) ... (a_i,4) ... (a_r,1)}`, with `0 < a_1 < a_2 < ...< a_i < ... < a_r` How can I to plot these coordinates?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `symbolic x coords={...}` and `xtick=data`

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[symbolic x coords={$a_1$,$a_2$,$a_i$,$a_r$},xtick=data,]
\addplot+[ycomb] plot coordinates
    {($a_1$,3) ($a_2$,2) ($a_i$,4) ($a_r$,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Гарнак Олэговытц You are welcome. Have a nice day. :)